# Redes Neurais can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, numpy, inteligência-artificial, redes-neurais

Olá, preciso implementar um perceptron para classificar linearmente 2 especies (Iris).

Já vasculhei a internet por soluções e não consigo sair do problema

Peguei um código na internet e tentei aplicar ao meu csv apenas para ver se dava algum resultado mas como sou iniciante em python não sei como contornar a situação. Se alguém puder me dar uma luz agradeço.

[LINK iris.csv](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/ad85495beec48c6630eb45b236514a51/iris.csv)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class Perceptron(object):

    def __init__(self, eta=0.01, epochs=50):
        self.eta = eta
        self.epochs = epochs

    def train(self, X, y):

        self.w_ = np.zeros(1 + X.shape[1])
        self.errors_ = []

        for _ in range(self.epochs):
            errors = 0
            for xi, target in zip(X, y):
                update = self.eta * (target - self.predict(xi))
                self.w_[1:] +=  update * xi
                self.w_[0] +=  update
                errors += int(update != 0.0)
            self.errors_.append(errors)
        return self

    def net_input(self, X):
        return np.dot(X, self.w_[1:]) + self.w_[0]

    def predict(self, X):
        return np.where(self.net_input(X) >= 0.0, 1, -1)

df = pd.read_csv('/home/DIRETORIO/iris.csv', header=None)

# setosa and versicolor
y = df.iloc[0:100, 4].values
y = np.where(y == 'Iris-setosa', -1, 1)

# sepal length and petal length
X = df.iloc[0:100, [0,2]].values

%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions

ppn = Perceptron(epochs=10, eta=0.1)

ppn.train(X, y)
print('Weights: %s' % ppn.w_)
plot_decision_regions(X, y, clf=ppn)
plt.title('Perceptron')
plt.xlabel('sepal length [cm]')
plt.ylabel('petal length [cm]')
plt.show()

plt.plot(range(1, len(ppn.errors_)+1), ppn.errors_, marker='o')
plt.xlabel('Iterations')
plt.ylabel('Misclassifications')
plt.show()
```

-- ERRO QUANDO TENTO RODAR NO JUPYTER (LINHA 25)--

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-10-c97f88eafcb5> in <module>
  5 ppn = Perceptron(epochs=10, eta=0.1)
  6 
----> 7 ppn.train(X, y)
  8 print('Weights: %s' % ppn.w_)
  9 plot_decision_regions(X, y, clf=ppn)

<ipython-input-8-7b4ff7d686b6> in train(self, X, y)
 15             errors = 0
 16             for xi, target in zip(X, y):
---> 17                 update = self.eta * (target - 
self.predict(xi))
 18                 self.w_[1:] +=  update * xi
 19                 self.w_[0] +=  update

<ipython-input-8-7b4ff7d686b6> in predict(self, X)
 26 
 27     def predict(self, X):
---> 28         return np.where(self.net_input(X) >= 0.0, 1, -1)

<ipython-input-8-7b4ff7d686b6> in net_input(self, X)
 23 
 24     def net_input(self, X):
---> 25         return np.dot(X, self.w_[1:]) + self.w_[0]
 26 
 27     def predict(self, X):

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Comment: Vc tem que implementar o perceptron? mesmo que copiando? não pode usar uma lib? Poste tambem o erro que esta ocorrendo.

Comment: Verifique o tipo do valor que o pd.read_csv() , retorna, use a função type(), e poste um trecho do seu .CSV

Comment: @Sidon Sim tenho que implementá-lo Não posso usar outras libs somente as que ja estou usando. Acrescentei o erro no post, tinha esquecido. Valeu

Comment: @FourZeroFive Não entendi muito bem mas se fiz certo retornou <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> os dados do csv são todos float

Comment: Use o type pra testar um único elemento do retorno

Comment: Então.. Esse erro é relativamente fácil de descobrir a causa, com alguns testes alguem vai acabar te ajudando, só não entendi o que o erro tem a ver com "redes neurais" sugiro mudar o titulo.

Answer (score 0):

O problema está no dataset, tente usar este aqui: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data.

O dataset que você está tentando usar tem cabeçalho e você colocou como parâmetro header=None.

O seu código funcionou perfeitamente para mim utilizando o dataset do link acima.